# Вызов функции JS через множество элементов с классом

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции

Здравствуйте. Возможно вопрос глуп, но все же. Как можно вызывать функцию при триггере клика через элементы с классом?

Например есть функция `function a(){ some code...}` и есть множество `<span class="hop">BTN</span>`, при клике на любой из элементов с классом `hop` вызывается функция `a();`.

Пробую так, но не срабатывает(в консоли нет ошибок):

```js
function a(){
code...
}

let b = document.querySelectorAll('.hop');
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
  b[i].click = function(){a();}
}
```

```html
<span class="hop">btn1</span>
<span class="hop">btn2</span>
<span class="hop">btn3</span>
<span class="hop">btn4</span>
```

```
    var sele = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch');

function www(){
    alert('wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww');
}
for (var i = 0; i < sele.length; i++) {
    sele[i].onclick = function (){www();}
}
```

**Переформулирую вопрос.**

Нужно добавить атрибут `data` для существующего `span`

Пробую это сделать так

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('span.selected');

    for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
        sel[i].setAttribute('bme',"Color&size");
    }
```

Выполняться должно при клике на элементы с одним классом, пробую так

```
    var sele = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch');
for (var i = 0; i < sele.length; i++) {
    sele[i].onclick = function (){www();}
}
```

Массив `sele` при алерт в цикле вызова функции `www();` не срабатывает

Полный код таков

```
var sele = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch');


function www(){
    alert('wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww');

    var sel = document.querySelectorAll('span.selected');

    for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
        sel[i].setAttribute('bme',"Color&size");
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < sele.length; i++) {
    sele[i].onclick = function (){www();}
}
```

Проблема в том, что функция не запускается. Нужно добавлять атрибут на элементы с классом `selected` (класс уже добавляется при клике на элемент)

Comment: `b[i].addEventListener('click', a);` и `length`, а не `lenght`

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день

У вас ошибка в слове length

Всё просто:

```
const onClick = e => console.log(e);

document.querySelectorAll('.hop')
    .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', onClick));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w4macw8d/

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться "Фрагментом кода"

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо, но ваш код, почему то не работает на моем сайте(

Comment: Советую открыть дебаггер в хроме и посмотреть где возникают проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь я тебя правильно понял....

```js
var sele = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch');

for (let i = 0; i < sele.length; i++) {
  sele[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < sele.length; i++) {
      sele[i].classList.remove('selected');
      sele[i].removeAttribute('bme');
    }
    this.classList.add('selected');
    this.setAttribute('bme', 'Color&size');
    console.log(sele)
  })
}
```

```html
<span class="swatch">btn1</span>
<span class="swatch">btn2</span>
<span class="swatch">btn3</span>
<span class="swatch">btn4</span>
```

Comment: Про length это я опечатался тут) Ваш пример работает здесь, но аналогично на моем сайте он не работает, консоль молчит, класс вызывается верно, не было таких ситуаций?

Comment: а что в консоли? может ошибки? как понять здесь работает а на сайте нет?

Comment: Тут в смысле через кнопку "Выполнить код", а на сайте не работает в смысле при написании идентичного кода. В консоли нет ошибок(кроме не загруженной фотки, но это не то)

Comment: Влад, что бы понять, что именно не работает и почему, придется добавить пример когда который у тебя на сайте в вопрос...

Comment: Код добавил, но он аналогичен. Возможно вам будет проще посмотрев на сайте. Куда я могу скинуть ссылку?

Comment: Сюда, можно скинуть... комментом...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69671/discussion-between---and-air).